# How do I receive payment from the USA to my current account in India

Tags: india, payment, transaction, online

I am setting up a small time company that renders online marketing solutions to USA clients. In this line of business, most Indian companies project themselves as US companies and they have a US bank account linked up to their Indian bank accounts. But I would like to be transparent and receive the payments to my current account in India.

Could anyone tell me the best and easiest way for me and my clients to transact without having any charges or fees?

Please help me understand the best way to receive payments from my US clients.

Thank you. 
Pradeep

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing called best;
Depending on the amounts there are several options and each will cost some money.

If your business is still small customers are individuals try PayPal it will be easy for everyone.

The other options are accepting Credit Card, you would need to set-up card gateway on your website etc

Simple wire transfer, it will cost more both for your customers and to you.